# VBA code or formula to Extract and Insert Value based on cell content

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Cell M38]

Simply I am having a school project so I want a code that will extract the first seven characters of cell M38 and insert the output in cell N38 then repeat such that it will extract the next seven characters in cell N39 and so on..

But if the code extract a cell containing a ";" insert as an empty cell then after that extract the next seven characters in cell M83

[image: Wanted Result]

---

[image: Problem]

Problem 1:

that after extracting the seven characters after the ";" the function began to fail

Problem 2:

it does not insert an empty cell if the cell contain ";"

---

I tried this ,but sadly didn't work

```
Sub ExtractFirstSevenCharacters()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 36 To 50
        Range("L" & i - 29).Value = Left(Range("K" & i).Value, 7)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("L7:L31").Value = Split(Application.Trim(Replace(Range("M38"),";",""))," ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it.

```
' Assuming digits in M38 are group in 7 digits.
Sub ExtractCharacters()
    Dim arr
    Dim sTxt As String
    sTxt = Trim(Replace(Range("M38"), ";", ""))
    arr = Split(sTxt)
    Range("L7").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Split(sTxt))
End Sub
```

Comment: The data in cell M38 shows that " ; " is surrounded by spaces. Your code creates a line with no data in each such case. You need to change the line sTxt = Trim(Replace(Range("M38"), ";", "")) to: sTxt = Application.Trim(Replace(Range("M38"), ";", "") ) as seen in @Scott Craner's comment. VBA's Trim removes leading and trailing whitespace while Application.Trim additionally collapses consecutive intervening spaces into one. For safety is better to replace ";" with " "